# Problems with unicode text in TexText extension for Inkscape

Tags: unicode, rendering

I'm trying to embed unicode text inside LaTeX in Inkscape using the TexText extension. Latin text looks fine, but when I apply this preamble:

```
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

I get the following result:
[image: Screenshot]

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?
I'm using Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon 64-bit.

Comment: Tried doing the same thing on Windows 7. Latin text works alright, but cyrillic letters just don't show up.

Comment: do you need the compilation to happen in `inkscape` envrionment? can you switch to `TeX` environment and do it? For instance, save the file with a `.pdf_tex` extension and include that output generated in a `.tex` file and compile it in `TeX` environment. May be that could work (given that you have necessary packages with you). (workflow: `File --> save as --> save as type = .pdf --> text output options = omit texts in PDF and create LaTeX files`). You will end up getting a pdf with no texts and a `.pdf_tex` which you can now include to substitute the texts and get the languages you need.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by installing the `texlive` distribution, with the preamble:

```
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
```

Result:

[image: screenshot]